# Heading angle calculation using current lat/long from the GPS

Tags: gps, angle, arduino-ide, haversine, atan2

The aim of my work is given in the algorithm below.

1. Initialize the H/W; wait until GPS module has a valid fix and then start the motor.
2. Get actual position from the GPS.
3. Calculate the distance and heading information to the next waypoint.
4. Compare the actual heading with the current heading angle and feed the difference to the motors.
5. When the actual position is close to the first waypoint, switch to the next waypoint.
6. If/when the last waypoint is reached, stop the motor.
7. If not go to step 2.

I'm calculating the distance between a pre-defined coordinate and the current location using Haversine formula. I need heading angle for the same pair of coordinates. But when I use the **atan2** formula and compile using the Arduino IDE, I am getting the angle as 0.05,0.03. Am I doing it wrong? can the heading angle be calculated for points within a proximity of 10m?

**formula**

```
double y = sin(dlon) * cos(lat2);
double x = ((cos(lat1) * sin(lat2)) - (sin(lat1) * cos(lat2) * cos(dlon)));
double brng = atan2(y, x);
```

Comment: Can you show some of the input data you are using? Why are you getting two numbers from a function that returns one?